# Scheme: Using Abstract List Functions without Recursion

Tags: scheme

How can I write a function using abstract list functions (`foldr`, `foldl`, `map`, and `filter`) without recursion that consumes a list of numbers `(list a1 a2 a3 ...)` and produces the alternating sum `a1 - a2 + a3 ...`?

Answer (score 8):

Here's a hint:

```
a1 - a2 + a3 - a4 ... aN
```

is the same as

```
a1 - (a2 - (a3 - (a4 - ... (aN - 0) ...)))
```

Is it obvious how to solve it now?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
(define (sum-abstract-list-functions lst)
  (car
   (foldl
    (lambda (e acc)
      (cons (+ (car acc) (* e (cdr acc)))
            (- (cdr acc))))
    '(0 . 1)
    lst)))
```

I'm only using `foldl`, `cons`, `car`, `cdr`. The trick? accumulating two values: the actual sum (in the `car` part of the accumulator), and the current sign (+/-1 in the `cdr` part of the accumulator). The accumulator gets initialized in 0 for the sum and +1 for the sign, and at the end I return the sum, the `car` part of the accumulator. Use it like this:

```
(sum-abstract-list-functions (list 1 2 3 4 5))
> 3
```

**EDIT :**

As has been pointed out, this solution is the simplest of all:

```
(define (sum-abstract-list-functions lst)
  (foldr - 0 lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework?  Well, we can split this problem into two subproblems:

- Take a list `(a1 a2 a3 a4 ... a2n-1 a2n)` and alternately negate elements from it, to produce `(a1 (- a2) a3 (- a4) ... a2n-1 (- a2n))`.
- Sum the elements of that resulting list.

The second part is the trivial one:

```
(define (sum xs)
  (foldl + 0 xs))
```

The first is the harder one, but it's not too hard. You need to transform the list while keeping a boolean state that indicates whether you're examining an even or an odd element, and negate or not accordingly.  I can see three ways of doing this:

- The mutational way: put the state into the closure that you pass to a `map`.  The closure then modifies its environment from one call to the next.
- Keep the state in the fold results: the fold result is a pair that contains the "real" result and the state as an element.
- Use a different sort of abstract list function.

Here's an example of the third approach (and if this is for homework, I bet your teacher may well be incredulous you came up with it):

```
(define (contextual-foldr compute-next
                          compute-init
                          advance-context
                          left-context
                          xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      (compute-rightmost-result left-context)
      (compute-next left-context
                    (car xs)
                    (contextual-foldr compute-next
                                      compute-init
                                      advance-context
                                      (advance-context (car xs) left-context)
                                      (cdr xs)))))

(define (contextual-map contextual-fn advance-context left-context xs)
  (contextual-foldr (lambda (left elem rest)
                      (cons (fn left elem) rest))
                    '()
                    advance-context
                    left-context
                    xs))

(define (alternate-negations xs)
  (contextual-map (lambda (negate? elem)
                    (if negate?
                        (- elem)
                        elem))
                  not
                  #f
                  xs))
```